# When more load in the spring boot application using Mysql Connection pool Timeout

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, kubectl

I am using Spring Boot application to connected MYSQL DB using application.properties based configurations,

I am having a connection issue every 30 sec,

when I do load testing time getting connection pool issue.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=300
```

I have configure the maximum size is 300 of connections by setting the  property. By default, this is set to 10. I have increased this, it's recommended way ?

I am using kubectl using cluster based application is running, when second pod running it is same replica of this application. I am getting 600 connections, AWS RDS maximum limit is 1000 connections only.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting? The questions are very hard to understand, could you please explain a little bit further?

Comment: I am getting connection pool error

Comment: Generally those errors come from in proper tx managmeent and/or messing around with connections (or JPA entitymanagers) yourself instead of letting spring manage those. Leading to connection leaks. Without seeing stacktraces and what you are doing in your code this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: The connection pool error impossible to fix, rather than if you have a communication exception you should post a log.